# Climate research and mathematics

Tags: differential-geometry, research

I'm not sure if this question belongs here, but I want to try:

I Am currently working on my master thesis on the topic differential geometry and wave maps. My plan was to start my PhD studies in this field.

Now, expecially lately, I am dealing with the topics of climate change and the dangers that could occur in the future.
I would really like to connect my career choices with research and work on climate change but I don't know how to.

I know that applied maths are used in modelling etc. so this would be an option, but I also would like to stick with PDEs and differential geometry.

Now my question: are there research fields, where differential geometry is used for research on climate change?

(Really sorry for the english)

Comment: The forces like Coriolis forces due to curved and rotating paths are complex and no dominating theory exists. I wish you best of luck. How far have you progressed yet?

Comment: progressed what?